# Kotlin class of unknown type as a method parameter

Tags: kotlin

How to write similar method in Kotlin? How to replace this question mark wildcard in kotlin?

```
private String doit(Class<?> c) {
  //body
}
```

My last attempt was:

```
fun doit(clazz: Class<Any>) : String {
    //body
}
```

Comment: The equivalent of `?` in Java is `*` in Kotlin.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @MarkoTopolnik , check out this link https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Comment: @SatejS yeah I read it but seems skipped this somehow

Comment: No problem, you want to go all the way to the bottom! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcard in Kotlin is: *
So, you can write:

```
fun doSth(clazz: KClass<*>) { /* ... */ }
```